# Make headings start at h2 in Gatsby markdown

Tags: markdown, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby to build a basic blog website. I've run into an issue, which is that my existing blog posts use `#` headings within them, but my Gatsby blog has an h1 at the top of the page. I'd like for `#` in Markdown to become an h2, `##` to be an h3, etc...

Is there an easy way to achieve this? `gatsby-transformer-remark` doesn't seem to have many options available, and even if it did I'm struggling to find an option on remark-parse or remark-stringify which would suit my purposes. I'd rather not write my own plugin if it can be avoided.

Comment: This is definitely something that would be handled by a plugin. However, tool recommendations are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using the `rehype-react` module. In your blog-post template, add

```
import rehypeReact from 'rehype-react'

const renderAst = new rehypeReact({
  createElement: React.createElement,
  components: {
    h1: props => <h2>{props.children}</h2>,
    h2: props => <h3>{props.children}</h3>,
    // ...
  },
}).Compiler
```

and replace

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }} />
```

with

```
{
  renderAst(post.htmlAst)
}
```

and change `html` to `htmlAst` in your graphql query.

[Here](https://using-remark.gatsbyjs.org/custom-components/) is a more advanced example on using remark & gatsby.